# Why does adding Navigation Component cause gradle error " error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found."

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx

My Android app has been working fine up until now in Android Studio, but when I add these lines of code to my Android Studio project to try and use Android's Navigation Component (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started), I keeping getting gradle errors.

```
// Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

One of these errors is about dialogCornerRadius not found:

```
.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-1.0.0.aar/dd9096ce87096c8058dc92354e7f3db2/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml
Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
```

I have read on other posts that the problem is related to my compile sdk version, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to change my app build.gradle code to solve the problem:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    def support_version = "26.1.0"
    def nav_version = "2.1.0"

    // Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Added to avoid dependency conflict
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'

    // Added to use tab layouts in MainActivity
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

When I try to change the line

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

I get different gradle errors. (I thought that might work though since it seems to be where the different version is). The error is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.
```

I followed the link in the error for this and am still lost.

Would anyone be able to help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

You have to use:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

Also you are mixing androidx and support libraries together and it is wrong.
**[Migrate to androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).**

Comment: But why can't I stay at compileSDKVersion 28? And what do you mean by mixing libraries? Aren't they two separate ones?

Comment: @Gomes In your build.gradle you are using compileSdkVersion 26. Also in your are using both support and androidx libraries together, and you can't do it.

Comment: But why can't you use both support and androidx libraries together?